# Calculate how many days to go until I have lived 25,000 days, and what that date will be

Tags: python, date

I wrote the program below to calculate how many days I have been alive, and a friend wanted to know on what date in the future will he hit 25,000 days.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
print("Mike")
birthdatetime = dt.datetime(1963, 4, 1)
age = now - birthdatetime
print(age)
```

I want to figure out a way to determine on what date I hit 25,000 days.

Comment: Alright, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the birthday and add 25000 days to it using timedelta.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
date(1963, 4, 1) + timedelta(days = 25000)
# datetime.date(2031, 9, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Use timedelta, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

```
    import datetime as dt
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    print("Andrew")
    birthdatetime = dt.datetime(1963, 6, 13,)
    age = now - birthdatetime
    print(age)
```

Comment: Do accept the answer if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: I actually don't know how to do that!  :)

Comment: No worries. Read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)